# Shuffle inside array php

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

how to shuffle arrays in array ? I tried lots of way but I can't achieve that. I think it's very simple but I'm stuck on that.

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12011190
            [1] => 12011158
            [2] => 12011583
            [3] => 12012107
            [4] => 12011222
            [5] => 12010638
            [6] => 12013836
            [7] => 12012232
            [8] => 12011256
            [9] => 12010007
            [10] => 12012531
            [11] => 12012182
            [12] => 12013253
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12011565
            [1] => 12010020
            [2] => 12011352
            [3] => 12014366
            [4] => 12011879
            [5] => 12011449
        )
)
```

I want to shuffle within arrays. I hope explain...

Comment: which value you want to shuffle and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a recursive multi-level function you can use.

```
function shuffle_array($arr) {
    if (!is_array($arr)) return $arr;
    shuffle($arr);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $a) {
        if (is_array($a)) {
            $arr[$key] = shuffle_array($a);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}

print_r(shuffle_array($array));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one is my solution. You saved my day.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, you can do it like this (assuming you want to shuffle every sub-array independently):

```
foreach($array AS &$element) {
    shuffle($element);
}
```

Or maybe like this:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $key) {
    shuffle($value);
});
```

Comment: `array_walk` is suitable for me. Thanks for the response, But Vlad Preda's answer is better for my code. (Next answer)